# Move a specific tag to different place with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I
     have a question. I need to move an specific tag of a XML to another tag, but I need to clear this tag when I move it.

Specifically, I need to move the following tag and your content `<ns1:eSocial xmlns:ns1="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtTabEstab/v02_03_00">` and put this inside this tag `<ns0:evento Id=""/>`.

Like this:

```
<ns0:evento Id="">
<ns1:eSocial xmlns:ns1="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtTabEstab/v02_03_00">
.
.
.
</ns1:eSocial>
</ns0:evento>
```

See the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns0:eSocial xmlns:ns0="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">
       <ns0:envioLoteEventos grupo="">
          <ns0:ideEmpregador>
             <ns0:tpInsc/>
             <ns0:nrInsc/>
          </ns0:ideEmpregador>
          <ns0:ideTransmissor>
             <ns0:tpInsc/>
             <ns0:nrInsc/>
          </ns0:ideTransmissor>
          <ns0:eventos>
             <ns0:evento Id=""/>
             <ns1:eSocial xmlns:ns1="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtTabEstab/v02_03_00">
                <ns1:evtTabEstab Id="">
                   <ns1:ideEvento>
                      <ns1:tpAmb/>
                      <ns1:procEmi/>
                      <ns1:verProc/>
                   </ns1:ideEvento>
                   <ns1:ideEmpregador>
                      <ns1:tpInsc/>
                      <ns1:nrInsc/>
                   </ns1:ideEmpregador>
                   <ns1:infoEstab>
                      <ns1:inclusao>
                         <ns1:ideEstab>
                            <ns1:tpInsc/>
                            <ns1:nrInsc/>
                            <ns1:iniValid/>
                            <ns1:fimValid/>
                         </ns1:ideEstab>
                         <ns1:dadosEstab>
                            <ns1:cnaePrep/>
                            <ns1:aliqGilrat>
                               <ns1:aliqRat/>
                               <ns1:fap/>
                               <ns1:aliqRatAjust/>
                               <ns1:procAdmJudRat>
                                  <ns1:tpProc/>
                                  <ns1:nrProc/>
                                  <ns1:codSusp/>
                               </ns1:procAdmJudRat>
                               <ns1:procAdmJudFap>
                                  <ns1:tpProc/>
                                  <ns1:nrProc/>
                                  <ns1:codSusp/>
                               </ns1:procAdmJudFap>
                            </ns1:aliqGilrat>
                            <ns1:infoCaepf>
                               <ns1:tpCaepf/>
                            </ns1:infoCaepf>
                            <ns1:infoObra>
                               <ns1:indSubstPatrObra/>
                            </ns1:infoObra>
                            <ns1:infoTrab>
                               <ns1:regPt/>
                               <ns1:infoApr>
                                  <ns1:contApr/>
                                  <ns1:nrProcJud/>
                                  <ns1:contEntEd/>
                                  <ns1:infoEntEduc>
                                     <ns1:nrInsc/>
                                  </ns1:infoEntEduc>
                               </ns1:infoApr>
                               <ns1:infoPCD>
                                  <ns1:contPCD/>
                                  <ns1:nrProcJud/>
                               </ns1:infoPCD>
                            </ns1:infoTrab>
                         </ns1:dadosEstab>
                      </ns1:inclusao>
                      <ns1:alteracao>
                         <ns1:ideEstab>
                            <ns1:tpInsc/>
                            <ns1:nrInsc/>
                            <ns1:iniValid/>
                            <ns1:fimValid/>
                         </ns1:ideEstab>
                         <ns1:dadosEstab>
                            <ns1:cnaePrep/>
                            <ns1:aliqGilrat>
                               <ns1:aliqRat/>
                               <ns1:fap/>
                               <ns1:aliqRatAjust/>
                               <ns1:procAdmJudRat>
                                  <ns1:tpProc/>
                                  <ns1:nrProc/>
                                  <ns1:codSusp/>
                               </ns1:procAdmJudRat>
                               <ns1:procAdmJudFap>
                                  <ns1:tpProc/>
                                  <ns1:nrProc/>
                                  <ns1:codSusp/>
                               </ns1:procAdmJudFap>
                            </ns1:aliqGilrat>
                            <ns1:infoCaepf>
                               <ns1:tpCaepf/>
                            </ns1:infoCaepf>
                            <ns1:infoObra>
                               <ns1:indSubstPatrObra/>
                            </ns1:infoObra>
                            <ns1:infoTrab>
                               <ns1:regPt/>
                               <ns1:infoApr>
                                  <ns1:contApr/>
                                  <ns1:nrProcJud/>
                                  <ns1:contEntEd/>
                                  <ns1:infoEntEduc>
                                     <ns1:nrInsc/>
                                  </ns1:infoEntEduc>
                               </ns1:infoApr>
                               <ns1:infoPCD>
                                  <ns1:contPCD/>
                                  <ns1:nrProcJud/>
                               </ns1:infoPCD>
                            </ns1:infoTrab>
                         </ns1:dadosEstab>
                         <ns1:novaValidade>
                            <ns1:iniValid/>
                            <ns1:fimValid/>
                         </ns1:novaValidade>
                      </ns1:alteracao>
                      <ns1:exclusao>
                         <ns1:ideEstab>
                            <ns1:tpInsc/>
                            <ns1:nrInsc/>
                            <ns1:iniValid/>
                            <ns1:fimValid/>
                         </ns1:ideEstab>
                      </ns1:exclusao>
                   </ns1:infoEstab>
                </ns1:evtTabEstab>
                <ns2:Signature Id="" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                   <ns2:SignedInfo Id="">
                      <ns2:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=""/>
                      <ns2:SignatureMethod Algorithm="">
                         <ns2:HMACOutputLength/>
                      </ns2:SignatureMethod>
                      <ns2:Reference Id="" URI="" Type="">
                         <ns2:Transforms>
                            <ns2:Transform Algorithm="">
                               <ns2:XPath/>
                            </ns2:Transform>
                         </ns2:Transforms>
                         <ns2:DigestMethod Algorithm=""/>
                         <ns2:DigestValue/>
                      </ns2:Reference>
                   </ns2:SignedInfo>
                   <ns2:SignatureValue Id=""/>
                   <ns2:KeyInfo Id="">
                      <ns2:KeyName/>
                      <ns2:KeyValue>
                         <ns2:DSAKeyValue>
                            <ns2:P/>
                            <ns2:Q/>
                            <ns2:G/>
                            <ns2:Y/>
                            <ns2:J/>
                            <ns2:Seed/>
                            <ns2:PgenCounter/>
                         </ns2:DSAKeyValue>
                         <ns2:RSAKeyValue>
                            <ns2:Modulus/>
                            <ns2:Exponent/>
                         </ns2:RSAKeyValue>
                      </ns2:KeyValue>
                      <ns2:RetrievalMethod URI="" Type="">
                         <ns2:Transforms>
                            <ns2:Transform Algorithm="">
                               <ns2:XPath/>
                            </ns2:Transform>
                         </ns2:Transforms>
                      </ns2:RetrievalMethod>
                      <ns2:X509Data>
                         <ns2:X509IssuerSerial>
                            <ns2:X509IssuerName/>
                            <ns2:X509SerialNumber/>
                         </ns2:X509IssuerSerial>
                         <ns2:X509SKI/>
                         <ns2:X509SubjectName/>
                         <ns2:X509Certificate/>
                         <ns2:X509CRL/>
                      </ns2:X509Data>
                      <ns2:PGPData>
                         <ns2:PGPKeyID/>
                         <ns2:PGPKeyPacket/>
                      </ns2:PGPData>
                      <ns2:SPKIData>
                         <ns2:SPKISexp/>
                      </ns2:SPKIData>
                      <ns2:MgmtData/>
                   </ns2:KeyInfo>
                   <ns2:Object Id="" MimeType="" Encoding=""/>
                </ns2:Signature>
             </ns1:eSocial>
          </ns0:eventos>
       </ns0:envioLoteEventos>
    </ns0:eSocial>
```

Anybody help me? I don´t know how to create XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT-1.0 template puts all `ns1:eSocial` elements in `<ns0:evento Id="">` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtTabEstab/v02_03_00"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="ns1:eSocial">
      <ns0:evento Id="">  
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
      </ns0:evento>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If that's what you want...

Comment: More one question, I can edit dynamically the field Id="" of the tag <ns0:evento Id=""> ?

Anyway, thank you so much for the help of both of you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to fill the field dynamically.

Comment: Of course, e.g. `<xsl:template match="ns0:evento"><xsl:attribute name="Id"><xsl:value-of select="count(//node())"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can match `ns0:evento`, apply templates for its attributes and nodes (at least itself, but it will also keep child nodes if there are any) and copy the adjacent `ns1:eSocial` nodes as child of `ns0:evento`.

`ns1:eSocial` is matched as well with an empty template to suppress it at its original position in the document tree.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtTabEstab/v02_03_00"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:evento">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../ns1:eSocial"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:eSocial"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help